# .net core B2C / 3rd party JWT validation and authorization

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, jwt

.net core web api v3.1

Using Azure B2C to authenticate users and have some .net core 3.1 APIs that are outside of that direct workflow. Authenticated services will be calling my endpoints. Almost all of this is server to server.

I need to verify the token, claims, expiration etc. How can I best do that? Can I use the token alone to "authenticate" the user / caller within my .net core API? Can I protect my endpoints with the [Authorize] attribute? I am hoping to avoid the need to connect directly with Azure B2C but rather just rely on the token.

The JWT / .net core APIs examples that I find all include clients authenticating directly with B2C. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario an user interactively authenticates in an app against a third-party using OAuth2 and retrieves a JWT.

The app then requests an ASP.NET Core Web API (.net Core 3.1) by using this token. The API controllers have the `[Authorize]` Attribute and the token is checked using Azure B2C authentication.

I don't know if this exactly meets your scenario. But since it took me quite some time to get this running, I thought it might give you a hint.

This is how I set up the JWT-authentication.

```
// In the startup.cs:

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string clientId = "<guid-identifying-the-client>"
    string policy = "B2C_1A_Sample_Policy"
    string tenant = "sampletenant.onmicrosoft.com"
    string aadInstance = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={policy}"

    services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
        {
            opt.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(jwtOpt =>
        {
            jwtOpt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidAudience = clientId,
                AuthenticationType = policy
            };
            jwtOpt.ConfigurationManager =
                new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                    aadInstance, 
                    new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever())
                    {
                        RefreshInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
                    };
            });
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    //...
}
```

**Note:** The aad instance used in the sample above is [deprecated](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/b2c-deprecate-msol/) and needs to be migrated to b2clogin.com until December 4th, 2020

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try a bit later.